# mod_rewrite 301 redirect not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to set up a rewrite that will redirect this URL:

**/video-2011.php?video=150**

to this:

**/video/150/freeform-title-text-here/**

I have the rewrite working using this line in my HTACCESS:

```
RewriteRule ^video/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ video-2011.php?video=$1 [L]
```

But as soon I add R=301 into the mix, it breaks. Any ideas?

Here's the full HTACCESS when it breaks:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^video/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ video-2011.php?video=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean that it breaks? Does it say not found, preparing redirect, etc...?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, /video.php?video=150 doesn't redirect to /video/150/

Comment: I think that you are meaning to say /video/150 doesn't redirect to /video.php?video=150

Comment: @Connor Smith, I'm confused too. I think @Kevin is trying to keep the urls looking tidy. Which is why this should **redirect** /video.php?video=150 to /video/150/ and **rewrite** /video/150/ to /video.php?video=150

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be missing a line from your .Htaccess.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^video/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)$ video-2011.php?video=$1 [L]
#New
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/video/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^video=([0-9]+)&name=([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^video-2011.php$ video/%1/%2/? [R=301,L]
```

I assuming you want to **rewrite** the url if it is:

```
/video/150/freeform-title-text-here/
```

And **redirect** the url if it is:

```
/video-2011.php?video=150
```

to:

```
/video/150/freeform-title-text-here/
```

So this way it keeps the urls looking pretty and tidy.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

**Edit**

I've added in a RewriteCond to stop the second rewrite happening.

As the first rule will obviously rewrite:

```
/video/150/freeform-title-text-here/
```

Which means the query string you don't see:

```
/video-2011.php?video=150
```

Would of made the second rule happen too.

Comment: Thanks Tom, this is exactly what I'm trying to do. I have both RewriteRule's in my htaccess and the 301 doesn't seem to be redirecting this URL: /video-2011.php?video=150

Comment: Ammended answer, tested and works on my server. Try that and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the continue help Tom, unfortunately this results in an infinite redirect situation - "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

Comment: Strange, I tested it locally and it worked for me. I'll double check for you.

Comment: Needed a `RewriteCond`, tested and works fine now, let me know what you think. Updated answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay on this, thanks for all the help Tom this works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
RewriteRule ^video/([0-9]+)/ /video-2011.php?video=$1 [R=301,L,NC,QSA]
```

And yes it will redirect `/video/150/foo` to `/video.php?video=150` not the other way around as you've stated in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this is actually doing the opposite of what I was trying to achieve. As Tom mentioned above, I'm hoping to redirect */video-2011.php?video=150* to */video/150/*